# In ruby, how do I know what a memoist method is doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am now doing a development base on health-data-standards library (https://github.com/projectcypress/health-data-standards.git). In the file lib/health-data-standards/export/helper/scooped_view_helper.rb (https://github.com/projectcypress/health-data-standards/blob/master/lib/health-data-standards/export/helper/scooped_view_helper.rb) line 90, patient.entries_for_oid is called. But the method is not defined.

Under Pry environment, I tried " edit patient.entries_for_oid ". The editor open memoist/lib/memoist.rb (https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist/blob/master/lib/memoist.rb) at line 166. There I saw these code:

```
          module_eval <<-EOS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def #{method_name}(*args)
          reload = Memoist.extract_reload!(method(#{unmemoized_method.inspect}), args)

          skip_cache = reload || !(instance_variable_defined?(#{memoized_ivar.inspect}) && #{memoized_ivar} && #{memoized_ivar}.has_key?(args))
          set_cache = skip_cache && !frozen?

          if skip_cache
            value = #{unmemoized_method}(*args)
          else
            value = #{memoized_ivar}[args]
          end

          if set_cache
            #{memoized_ivar} ||= {}
            #{memoized_ivar}[args] = value
          end

          value
        end
      EOS
    end
```

But it doesn't make sense, what patient.entries_for_oid really does.

Any one knows that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method is [defined](https://github.com/projectcypress/health-data-standards/blob/09ffe3177d408ef2f8917026d7d3db7588cb676b/lib/health-data-standards/models/record.rb#L78-L88) on the `Record` model class. An instance of such a class is passed to the `entries_for_data_criteria` method in your helper.

You don't simply see the actual method source because the authors chose to use the [Memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) gem which can be used to wrap arbitrary methods to extend their behavior (in this case caching, or more precisely memoization).

Comment: So how could I debug that 'method'? It now filters out one of my important record.